# Nested sql query error in java

Tags: java, mysql, postgresql

> Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
>
> sql = "SELECT P1, P2 FROM "
>                       + "(SELECT (3959 * acos(cos(radians(T2.origin_lat)) * cos(radians( T1.origin_lat )) * cos(radians(T1.origin_lon) - radians(T2.origin_lon)) + sin(radians(T2.origin_lat)) * sin(radians(T1.origin_lat )))) "
>                       + "as dis,"
>                       + "T1.id as P1,T2.id as P2 FROM public.dummy T1  CROSS JOIN public.dummy T2  "
>                       + "where P1 != P2 ) res"
>                       + "where res.dis<=.05  order by P1";
>
> ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

Getting this error

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "res"
>     Position: 326

PS - Same query is working in MySQL.
Do this kind of view creation does not work in java?
What change should I make?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

P2 ) res" + "where

I'm not an expert, but how about putting space? :)

Comment: Pretty common 'SQL in code' error to the point where that's the first thing I look for when I do it.

Comment: Oh yeah ..Thanks for quick reply and sorry for this silly question

Comment: Is my solution right? I used to spend a whole day for this by forgetting to look for the space :)